# Pandas DataFrame append Series

Tags: pandas, series

I have the following table and series

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[], 'b':[]})
s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3])
df.b = s1

s2 = pd.Series([3,2,1])
s3 = pd.Series([4,5,6])
s4,s5,s6...
```

My objective is to append each series into column b in the data frame. But the problem is that I have to attach the series one by one in a loop.

The only way I can think of is

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[], 'b'=[]})
temp_df.b = s2
df.append(temp_df, ignore_index = True)
```

Is there a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: My answer is the same as your last question. Sequential appends in a loop is perhaps the _most_ expensive operation that can be done. The time complexity growth is near exponential as the dataframe increases in size each iteration and a complete copy needs to be generated of the dataframe with the new values. Collecting a list of Series from the loop then performing a single `concat` operation on that list is the fastest way to solve this type of problem.

Comment: you also asked this question previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333176/pandas-dataframe-attach-series

Comment: @HenryEcker The problem is that I am scraping Series data and won't able to collect the entire series at once. That's why I thought of only appending the existing series into the existing data frame. I guess in this case the only way to do this is to do it as I did at the cost of computing power?

Comment: You don't need to collect the entire series at once. You need to save all intermediate series in a list and _append_ or _concat_ once. Don't use pandas operations until you have _all_ the data collected. _Then_ start with the dataframe.

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm only able to collect the one series for one loop.